# MySQL query who return 0 or 1 according date

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(`expiry_date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%d %m %Y')
  FROM `my_subscriptions`
 WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]';
```

which returns `expiry_date` minus 7 days; let's call that the "returned date".

Now I would like compare this "returned date" against the current date (the time right now), returning `0` if the current date is less than or equal to the "returned date", and `1` if it's bigger.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want that as an output column in addition to the `DATE_FORMAT()`, or instead of it?

Comment: yes in the query itself...and instead of it... I must precise I'm not a sql guru...I have just a little knowledge for understand a bit what I do but nothing else..

Comment: I accepted an answer few hours ago and I see now this answer is no more published...why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) and also use `NOW()` for the current date time. Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOW() <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(`expiry_date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_expired FROM `my_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]';
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it return always 1. I checked in two user account where their expiration date are 20 07 2013 and 09 07 2014...

Comment: You need to use `Y-M-D` format as `NOW()` will return date in `Y-M-D` format see the edited answer